# Make main category always at top of columns when creating category listing

Tags: html, css

The following creates a listing of categories and subcategories in 3 columns.

But sometimes subcategories will be at the top of a column. How can I make it so that the Top level category is ALWAYS at the top of a column like the way Amazon does it: http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=sa_menu_top_fullstore/189-4849712-0706628

```
<ul style=" -webkit-column-count: 3; margin-top:50px;">
{% for cat in topcats %}
<li><a href="/parts/{{cat.id}}/dir/" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:18px;color:#FF761A;">{{cat.category}} </a>
{% for key, value in subcats.items %}
{% if key == cat %}
        {% for eachsubcat in value %}
        <h5 class="inline"><a href ="/parts/{{eachsubcat.id}}/dir/" style="text-decoration:none;">{{ eachsubcat }}</a></h5>
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

UPDATE: here's my JSFiddle code - http://jsfiddle.net/X6ay3/

Comment: You're missing the closing `</li>`

Comment: it's actually to the right if you scroll... but let me update the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul style=" -webkit-column-count: 3; margin-top:50px;">
    {% for cat in topcats %}
    <li>
<a href="/parts/{{cat.id}}/dir/" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:18px;color:#FF761A;">{{cat.category}} </a>
    {% for key, value in subcats.items %}
    {% if key == cat %}
            {% for eachsubcat in value %}
            <h5 class="inline"><a href ="/parts/{{eachsubcat.id}}/dir/" style="text-decoration:none;">{{ eachsubcat }}</a></h5>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </li> <!-- missing li-->
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks I made the changes you suggested, but it still doesn't seem to be doing this correctly.

Comment: Ok I added a jsfiddle link to the question :-)